# Invalid mutation LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to clone the array of records that is passed to the component and add some additional attributes to the cloned records however I always get the 'Invalid mutation: Cannot set "detailHeader" on "[object Object]". "[object Object]" is read-only.' error.

I have tried cloning it in the connectedCallback but still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
@api detailheaderfield;
@api detailbodyfield;
@track selectedRecords

@api
get records(){
    return this.selectedRecords;
}

set records(value){
    let records = [...value];
    records.forEach((record) => {
        record.detailHeader = record[this.detailheaderfield];
        record.detailField = record[this.detailbodyfield];
    });

    this.selectedRecords = records;
}
```

Comment: You need to deep clone `value` as it mutated when set from the parent. Also. the spread operator clones the array but not the elements inside that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Rahul's comment:

> You need to deep clone value as it mutated when set from the parent. Also. the spread operator clones the array but not the elements inside that.

I did a deep clone on the value by doing `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value));` and I was able to modify the records.

Answer (score 0):

Input parameters are read only. You must copy as Rahul said.